# How to use Angular CLI schematics in StackBlitz

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, stackblitz

I am using StackBlitz for testing and answering Angular related questions on Stackoverflow. I am manually creating Components, Services, Modules, etc. Is there a way to use Angular CLI in StackBlitz to speed up the process?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such option exist, #following

Answer (score 19):

There's an even simpler way: **right-click**

[image]

It's pretty neat in the sense that it creates everything and adds it to the `AppModule` just like angular-cli schematics.

Source:  https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/132#issuecomment-470386015

Also, you can drag and drop files from your local system to the stackblitz:

[image]

so you can generate everything on your local IDE or terminal and then drag and drop it to the stackblitz platform.

Comment: When I right click, I do not see the Angular Generator option, any idea why?